# How to summarise a data frame based on values occurring at unique data points in a particular column?

Tags: r, tidyverse

I've got a data frame `df` given by:

```
r  t s      v
1  1 a   4.50
2  1 b   3.00
3  2 c   3.22
4  3 d   2.00
5  3 a   5.00
6  1 c   1.00
7  1 f  14.00
8  2 b 144.00
9  3 c   2.00
10 4 a  22.00
11 2 a   2.20
12 3 e 232.00
13 4 g  45.00
14 3 g   4.30
15 3 b   3.20
16 4 b   2.00
17 4 c   2.60
```

and I want to convert this into another data frame `df1` as

```
r t    a     b    c  d   e    f  g
1 1  4.5   3.0 1.00 NA  NA 14.0 NA
2 2  2.2 144.0 3.22 NA  NA   NA NA
3 3  5.0   3.2 2.00  2 232 NA 4.3
4 4 22.0   2.0 2.60 NA  NA NA 45.0
```

where the `colnames` in `df1` are the unique values from `s` column in `df` and they are grouped by their occurrence in `t` column in df.

There won’t be any duplicates of ‘s’ in each ‘t’ so it can be assumed that each ‘s’ only appears once for every ‘t’ value.

Is there an easy way (using `dplyr` or similar) to manipulate the data in `df` to get `df1`?

Comment: When you have multiple rows with the same values of `t` & `s`, what do you want to do with the `v`'s? Would you want to average them, sum them, take the median, etc?

Comment: Try `library(reshape2); dcast(dat[-1], t ~ s)` then add column `r` if needed. Your expected output for cols `f` and `g` seems not correct.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to reshape data from long to wide format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5890584/how-to-reshape-data-from-long-to-wide-format)

Comment: I also used `reshape2`: `df1 <- dcast(df, t ~ s, value.var = "v")` . Example result is off.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm inferring that you might be having problems using answers from the duplicate target because you have included the row number as a column. We can `spread` on the table without the `r` column.Note that there are two values in rows 3 and 4 of the output which you appear to have misclassified in the example output; they should be under `g` and not `f`.

```r
library(tidyverse)
tbl <- read_table2(
"t s      v
1 a   4.50
1 b   3.00
2 c   3.22
3 d   2.00
3 a   5.00
1 c   1.00
1 f  14.00
2 b 144.00
3 c   2.00
4 a  22.00
2 a   2.20
3 e 232.00
4 g  45.00
3 g   4.30
3 b   3.20
4 b   2.00
4 c   2.60"
)
tbl %>%
  spread(s, v)
#> # A tibble: 4 x 8
#>       t     a     b     c     d     e     f     g
#>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1     1   4.5   3    1       NA    NA    14  NA  
#> 2     2   2.2 144    3.22    NA    NA    NA  NA  
#> 3     3   5     3.2  2        2   232    NA   4.3
#> 4     4  22     2    2.6     NA    NA    NA  45
```

<sup>Created on 2019-02-11 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Comment: Hi, we can assume that there won’t be any duplicates for ‘s’ in each ‘t’ so only one value of ‘s’ is present per ‘t’ value.